# How to hide the Autokey icon from Ubuntu top panel?

Tags: shortcut-keys, autokey

How is it possible to remove the icon of the AutoKey software on Ubuntu 20.04 from the top panel permanently?

[image: this icon should be removed.]

I have used the [Icon Hider](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/351/icon-hider/) extension, but in the next restart, it shows up again.

Answer (score 4):

For Ubuntu 20.04 or later you can follow these steps:

1. Open AutoKey.
2. Go to *Edit* → *Preferences*.
3. Uncheck the *Show a notification icon* option.

   [image: AutoKey menu]
4. Close the AutoKey window.
5. Click the AutoKey icon in the top bar and press *Quit*.

   [image: AutoKey icon menu]

   **Note:** The icon menu looks a bit different than yours on my Ubuntu 20.04 installation. I'm not sure why.
6. Start AutoKey again.

Autokey should now be running without an icon on the top bar.

Comment: This is the right answer, but keep in mind that the panel icon context menu has a number of useful options which can also include selected scripts to run - which is handy for less frequently used scripts that you can't remember the hotkeys for or don't even want to assign hotkeys to.